# Required field for Person snippet to preview in Google search results

Tags: google, seo, rich-snippets

Recently, I started using schema.org snippets. The first one was the [Person snippet](http://schema.org/Person). I did everything according to Google recommendation except for the fact that I don't need for example affiliation field and many others. I used just description, image, name. So the next step is to test how my page will be showed in Google search result, [Google Snippet Tools](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets) helps us in it. The example preview has a picture, looks great, but below the example it's written **Note that there is no guarantee that a Rich Snippet will be shown for this page on actual search results** and actually in google search results there is no any picture. FAQ wasn't very descriptive, I suspect there few required fields for every snippet, but I didn't find what they are.

Do you know what are required field for Person snippet (I also interested in Product)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [FAQ](http://knol.google.com/k/google-rich-snippets-tips-and-tricks#Who_is_eligible_for_Rich_Snippets%283F%29):

> Currently, review sites and social networking/people profile sites are eligible. We plan to expand Rich Snippets to other types of content in the future.

[Further down](http://knol.google.com/k/google-rich-snippets-tips-and-tricks#Why_am_I_seeing_%2822%29Insufficient_data_to_generate_the_preview%2822%29_in_the_Rich_Snippets_Testing_Tool%283F%29)(#2), there's a comment that "certain data is required in order to generate a rich snippet preview" but no actual information as to what that is. The word "required" barely shows up at schema.org at all, and only as part of explanations of properties, not whether one is necessary.

[Here's a post](http://groups.google.com/group/schemaorg-discussion/browse_thread/thread/746c22652126715b?pli=1) to the schema.org mailing list(now moved) from this August pointing out the obvious problem with this, to which there was no response.

Comment: ok, thanks, take a looks at this post [drupal schema](http://drupal.org/node/1351214) somewhere in the middle he points out that Image, affiliation, jobTitle are required fields. I don't know where it comes from.

Comment: You'll have to ask the person who wrote it. Note the mailing list message says something about getting some warnings from the validation tool. The info in that Drupal recipe was probably determined from some amount of experimenting; that's not the same as official documentation. Neither the schema.org docs nor Google's implementation notes say anything on the matter. That's bad because it means they could theoretically decide to change those requirements, breaking your implementation with no obvious notice to you.

Comment: Instead of Person, I'll try to use Thing snippet, it has only 4 fields and this is actually all I need. I am not sure if google will preview Thing, let's take a look